# Insert multidimensional array data into MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I need to insert array data into MySQL DB. My code is provided below. The problem is that `query` is equal to

> INSERT INTO `MyTab` (Array) VALUES
>   (Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array)

So, why do I get `Array` instead of array values?

```
$columns = array();
    $values = array();

    $columns[] = array('Num','appearanceTime');

    $curr_time = new DateTime();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_arr)) {
        $values[] = array($row['Num_arr'],$curr_time);
    }

    $cols = implode(",",$columns);
    $vals = implode(",",$values);

$query = "INSERT INTO `MyTab` ($cols) VALUES ($vals)";
```

UPDATE
This code returns Internal Server Error at the line `$vals = implode(...)`.

$columns = array('Num','appearanceTime','earliestTime');
    $values = array();

```
$curr_time = new DateTime();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_arr)) {
    $values[] = array($row['Num_arr'],$curr_time,$row['ETA']);
}

$cols = implode(",",$columns);

function get_values($arr) {
return '(' . implode(',', $arr) . ')';
}

$vals = implode(',', array_map('get_values', $values));

$query_queue = "INSERT INTO `MyTab` ('" . $cols . "') VALUES ('" . $vals . "')";
```

Comment: Try to remove the brackets after $columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values inside the arrays are arrays. You need to `implode` each of them, too:

```
$vals = implode(',', array_map(function($arr) {
    return '(' . implode(',', $arr) . ')';
}, $values));
```

As for the columns, I think you want:

```
$columns = array('Num','appearanceTime');
$values = array();
```

Not:

```
$columns = array();
$values = array();

$columns[] = array('Num','appearanceTime');
```

You'll also need to quote everything to put it in the query. You should use PDO or MySQLi and prepared statements instead of `mysql_` if you can.

---

Given PHP 5.2, the first example needs to be changed to:

```
function implode_comma($arr) {
    return '(' . implode(',', $arr) . ')';
}

# ...

$vals = implode(',', array_map('implode_comma', $values));
```

Comment: Thanks,I tried your updates. This one contains some syntax error: $vals = implode(',', array_map(function($arr) {
     return '(' . implode(',', $arr) . ')';
 }, $values)); Do you know what's the problem here?

Comment: Also, what is '$arr'? Is it a new variable? Or does it correspond to some of my variables?

Comment: @YouKuper: That's an anonymous function. Which version of PHP are you using? If it's less than 5.3, you'll need to change that into a real function and use `array_map('your_function', $values)` instead.

Comment: @YouKuper: You didn't pay attention. It's not `get_values($values)`. It's `'get_values'`.

Comment: Ok,I changed to 'get_values' and I placed the function get_values before $vals = implode(...); Now I get Internal Server Error at the line $vals = implode(...); Please see the complete  updated code.

Comment: @YouKuper: *"You'll also need to quote everything to put it in the query."*

Comment: Log says: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: @YouKuper: Well, you need to format your `DateTime` before inserting it. Do that while you're creating your array.

Comment: Thx. And how do I quote everything in the query? Isn't it enough to write ' " . $vals ." ' ?

Comment: @YouKuper: No, quote everything when you put it into the array in the first place.